# SSMS - Remove duplicate grouped values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL (SSMS) like so:

```
Group|item
1|desk
1|phone
1|book
2|desk
2|phone
3|desk
3|phone
3|book
4|Desk
4|phone
4|laptop
```

I want to remove any group where all of the items within the group exist within another group. If there are 2 or more groups that all have the exact same items then I only want to keep one instance of that group and get rid of the others.

In the example table I have above I would only keep groups 1 and 4, because all the items in group 2 already exist in group 1 and group 3 is just a duplicate of group 3.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I currently have a solution whereby I select the above table into a temporary table, join that table onto itself where group!=group, get a distinct count of items in the right table, count the  number of instances the items match and if the two numbers are the same I remove that group. (Because that would show all the items in that group exist in the group on the left hand side)

The problem with this solution is that by inner joining the table onto itself where the group numbers don't match, I'm having to create a table with an (x^2) - x number of rows and the real table I'm dealing with has over 30,000 Rows and I'd prefer to not create a table containing approximately 9 billion rows.

Also note that I have thousands of different items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select distinct t.group
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.group < t.group and t1.item = t.item);
```

`group` is a reserved keyword for SQL Server, so column naming with `group` is not recommend.

Comment: is there any harm in using  t1.group != t.group instead of  t1.group < t.group ?

Answer (score 1):

use not exists

```
  with cte as
    (
    select * from (
    select 1 as grp,'desk' as item union all
    select 1,'phone' union all
    select 1,'|book' union all
    select 2,'desk' union all
    select 2,'phone' union all
    select 3,'desk' union all
    select 3,'phone' union all
    select 3,'|book' union all
    select 4,'Desk' union all
    select 4,'phone' union all
    select 4,'laptop'
    ) t
    ) 
    select distinct t1.grp
    from cte t1
    where not exists (select 1 from cte t2 where t2.grp < t1.grp and t2.item = t1.item);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is rather complicated.  You can get groups that are equivalent by doing:

```
select grp, min(contained_in_group)
from (select t1.grp, t2.grp as contained_in_group
      from tt t1  join
           t t2
           on t1.item = t2.item 
      group by t1.grp, t2.grp, t1.num_grp
      having count(*) = count(t2.item) and count(*) = t1.num_grp
      ) x
group by grp;
```

You can see a [rextester](http://rextester.com/YVOXP47069) of this.

The actual result you want is:

```
select distinct min(contained_in_group)
from (select t1.grp, t2.grp as contained_in_group
      from tt t1  join
           t t2
           on t1.item = t2.item 
      group by t1.grp, t2.grp, t1.num_grp
      having count(*) = count(t2.item) and count(*) = t1.num_grp
      ) x
group by grp;
```